# Ищу аналог пробела в юникоде

Tags: java, unicode

*Вы знали что можно использовать кириллицу при названии переменных
 в java?*

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int abc = 3124;

    int жорап = 56334;

    int Ҧн̂ܔॵҦ = 54;

    int пи̅ʃʥс̺̄  = 234 + Ҧн̂ܔॵҦ;


    System.out.println(пи̅ʃʥс̺̄ );
  }
}

class петькин_Класс {

}
```

Примерно половина символов отсюда не вызывают вопросов у компилятора:

https://unicode-table.com/ru/

> Ищу аналог **пробела** в юникоде;

```
//чтобы
int red велосипед = 0;
//вместо 
int red_велосипед = 0;
```

"EDIT"

```
class redﾠplane {
// работающий пробел в названии класса (U+FFA0)
}
```

Comment: О господи, зачем?

Comment: Чтобы_использовать_пробел_вместо_нижнего_подчеркивания

Comment: Почитайте лучше принятые соглашения по оформлению стиля кода. То что Вы хотите сделать - это очень плохое решение, в том числе и использование кириллицы.

Comment: Давайте до конца определим вашу цель. Как мне видится, вы хотите заставить людей, которые будут читать ваш код, рвать на себе волосы и биться головой о стену в истерике, пытаясь понять, чем переменная `test` отличается от переменной `te‍st`. Если это так, то zero width joiner - ваш выбор, он гарантированно доведёт до психиатрической лечебницы процентов 10 из тех кто рискнёт почитать ваш код. В противном случае луше будет использовать в идентификаторах только латинский алфавит.

Comment: Попробуйте неразрывный пробел U+00A0

Comment: Выбирайте: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пробел#Другие_пробелы_в_Юникоде

Comment: ни один из вышеперечисленных пробелов не компилируется. Но зато есть фильтры 'HALFWIDTH HANGUL FILLER' (U+FFA0)   -> "ﾠ" <-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, мы знаем об этом малоизвестном факте. Чтобы компилировать исходники нужно просто задать кодировку исходников, типа:

```
javac -encoding "UTF-8" MyTest.java
```

Вместо `UTF-8` может стоять любая кодировка - да хоть бы и `KOI-8`

а вот такой номер:

```
int red велосипед = 0;
```

уже не пройдет, потому что пробел, равно как и символ табуляции являются разделителями и это невозможно изменить.

Ревнителям англоязычных идентификаторов советую иметь ввиду, что [наука умеет много гитик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA).

Я сам лично не сторонник, неанглоязычных идентификаторов, но увы жизнь более многогранна и уже сталкивался со случаями, когда кириллические идентификаторы активно юзаются иногда в довольно крупных проектах (в основном в оборонке).

Однако же, не премину ввернуть, что такое использование противоречит [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)